# Convert or add to empty list of list into 0

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an array that looks like this

```
a = [ [1], [2], [] , [4] ]
```

And I used "sum":

```
a = sum(a,[])
```

and got something like this:

```
a =(1,2,4)
```

The point here is that **I want to get something that looks like this**:

```
a = (1,2,0,4)
```

In the position of the "[]", I want a 0 because I want to transform that list of list into just a vector . Im kind new to python so there is a way to make this happen somehow like or fill the "[]" with 0 getting "[0]" and then applied sum or to say that if "[]" appears, it is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
a = [ [1], [2], [] , [4] ]
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if a[i]==[]:
        a[i]=[0]
a = sum(a,[])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension and tuple():

```
In : [ l[0] if l else 0 for l in a ]                                                                                       
Out: [1, 2, 0, 4]

In : tuple( [ l[0] if l else 0 for l in a ] )                                                                             
Out: (1, 2, 0, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for n, i in enumerate(a)
   if i == []:
      a[n] = [0]
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **list comprehension** (very *pythonic* :D) to replace all empty lists within `a` to a list containing 0:

```
a = [ [1], [2], [] , [4] ]
a = [[0] if not arr else arr for arr in a]
a = sum(a,[])
// a = [1, 2, 0, 4]
```

The line `if not arr` uses the inherent boolean-ness of lists, wherein if a list is empty its boolean value is `false`.